# Reusing persistence.xml between JavaEE and JavaSE environments

Tags: java, jpa, junit, openjpa, persistence.xml

I am doing JPA development mainly under WebSphere 7.0, which uses OpenJPA as its JPA provider.

I have the following `persistence.xml` file:

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="PU">
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/test</jta-data-source>
        ...
        ... Entities
        ...
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And, when running under WebSphere, things work as expected: OpenJPA performs a JNDI lookup for `jdbc/test` and JPA works its magic there.

Now, I'd like to write JUnit testers for my code. JUnit testers run under JavaSE, but I can't make it work. I realize that the JUnit tester has to somehow provide OpenJPA with the connection information to the database (as `jdbc/test` means nothing in JavaSE), but I get different errors depending on what I try.

### What I tried:

**Alternative 1 (works, but...)**

Commented out `jta-data-source` and, in the Java code, provided a `Map` to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory`. The map contained the key `openjpa.ConnectionFactory`, with the value being a pre-constructed `OracleDataSource` instance with all connection properties in it.

This *works*: JPA can connect to the database. However, I don't like this option because, again, it implies that I have to modify my `persistence.xml` file depending on whether I run on JavaEE or JavaSE.

**Alternative 2**

Keeping `jta-data-source`, and trying passing a `Map` to `Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory` containing all sorts of properties that I thought would be helpful. No matter what I try, I get the following error:

```
Caused by: <openjpa-2.0.2-SNAPSHOT-r422266:1389965 fatal user error>
org.apache.openjpa.util.InvalidStateException: Could not perform automatic lookup of EJB
container's javax.transaction.TransactionManager implementation. Please ensure that you
are running the application from within an EJB 1.1 compliant EJB container, and then set
the org.apache.openjpa.ManagedRuntime property to the appropriate value to obtain the
TransactionManager.
```

... That implies that OpenJPA is still trying to perform a JNDI lookup, even though I'm passing a map with keys instructing it to do otherwise.

Has anyone else encountered this? is it possible at all to use a JNDI-"enabled" `persistence.xml` in a JavaSE environment, by passing OpenJPA properties to override the JNDI lookup?

(By the way: What I do know is that, under JavaSE, the `transaction-type` attribute for `persistence-unit` defaults to `RESOURCE_LOCAL`, so that can't be the root of my problem)

Comment: Can't you have two persistence-units within persistence xml say PU which is JTA based and another unit say PUTest which is Resource Local where in using PU in normal case and PUTest for junits?

Comment: I definitely could, but then I'd have to repeat the content of the `persistence-unit` element (class definitions, references to ORM files etc.), which I'd highly prefer to avoid if at all possible.

Comment: FWIW JNDI doesn't have to "mean nothing" in JavaSE, if you use a stand-alone JNDI provider ('oocjndi' being one such).

Comment: @DataNucleus wasn't aware of that. Interesting alternative. Actually, may solve other issues revolving around testing JavaEE code in a JavaSE environment!

Comment: I foresee a possible problem with the fact that you're defining a JTA datasource though.

Comment: You maybe ought to raise an issue on OpenJPA to respect overriding datastore connection props so they're aware of the particular situation (I implemented the equivalent in DataNucleus JPA some time ago - it's not explicitly defined in the JPA spec in terms of what can be overridden). Be aware that you can also go stand-alone for jta, an example 'omjjta' with 'jotm'.

Comment: @Gimby, indeed, from what I was able to gather from the JPA 2.0 spec, nothing is mentioned about how `jta-data-source` / `non-jta-data-source` are treated in a JavaSE environment. Bizarre that they do differentiate (to my recollection) between JavaSE/JavaEE with respect to the `transaction-type` attribute...

Comment: You and I must be reading different documentation then, what I read way back when was pretty clear on the subject. Then again I used mostly books and not the specifications directly. I prefer a text written to instruct rather than provide clinical specifications.